# R Turn Column into Object

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn R. I've spent 4 hours trying to understand what is most likely the easiest issue ever. How do I turn a column into an object?

All I want to do at this stage is a linear regression with the contents of two columns. In Stata, I could just enter something like

reg column1 column2

In R, it seems I first need to turn the column into an object. I understand that turning numbers, string or logical values into objects is pretty simple (ie x <- 7). How do I do this for an entire column? My process so far:

1. Turned Excel file with headers into a CSV
2. Opened CSV in RStudio

I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. I've actually tried. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your data, e.g. using `dput(data)` (assuming `data` is the object your read your CSV file into).

Comment: If you read your data into a `data.fame`, call it myDF, then you want `X<-myDF$XXXX` where you replace `XXXX` with the column name  of the column you want.

Comment: Building off of what John Paul said, if you want to do a linear regression, it's a simple as `model <- lm(col1 ~ col2, data = myDF)`.

Comment: I am sorry @TejaK, I did not want to post a copy of your comment. I was editing my answer and I just didn't saw your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for a simple linear regression is just lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + etc). In R, there are two places that these variables could be: Either they are simply in the global environment (they show up by name under the "values" heading in your data), or they are a subset of some dataframe. If they are a subset of a dataframe, to call them you would need to write `dataframe$varname`, not just `varname`. So your linear model would have to be `lm(df$y ~ df$x1 + df$x2)`, or alternatively `lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)`. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Example, Suppose the column you want to use is the second one just

```
dat2 <- data[ , 2 ]
```

but I think It would be more convenient to set the `data = <your_data>` argument of the `lm` functions and use just the name of the columns.
Here is an example with the `iris` data set.

```
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

As you can see you just use the name of the columns since you specified in which `data =` R has to search.

Use `summary(reg)` to see a summary of the regression.

Answer (score 0):

After you read the data using something like:

```
MyData <- read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

you can view the columns by calling them by their header name (top entry of each column).

ex.

```
MyData[1]
```

To make them objects:

```
object1=MyData[1]
```

to make it a sublist. To make it a vector:

```
vector1=MyData[,1]
```